# Java webengine concurrency with spark web service

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice, javafx-webengine

I am trying to create a web service that can spawn a crawler using `com.ui4j.api.browser.BrowserFactory` (JavaFX webview) since `getBrowser` method can only return one instance, as is also documented.

I am trying to run this concurrently in separate threads so that I can spawn multiple browsers at once.

Have also followed : [Thread safe and concurrent use, multiple instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896337/thread-safe-and-concurrent-use-multiple-instances)

But I don't understand how can I add criteria's dynamically / create callables dynamically since all this code is running behind a Webservice made from `JavaSpark`

This is my code :

```
import static spark.Spark.get;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Runcrawl {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        get("/crawl/:keyword", (req, res) - > {
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newWorkStealingPool(3);
            return executor.submit(() - > {
                String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                System.out.println("threadName : " + threadName);
                return launchBrowser();
            }).get();
        });

    }
}
```

Right now I am using `executor.submit().get()` , which runs fine but blocks the thread thus not letting me launch a separate browser.

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.